# Yii: Multiple events best practices

Tags: php, events, yii, exception, error-handling

Events in Yii looks great, but several questions still wakes me at night:

- If I raise an event and create several PHP event handler classes in chain, can I pass different data between them (like return value)? 
  Is the event designed for this goal? As far as I see, the event seems to be one-direction way of notification and passing data back is not a common practice, is that correct?

  Lets say:

  I have 3 handlers : **Handler1**, **Handler2**, **Handler3** executed in this order. Each Handler concatenates some string data. 
  Can I pass the concatenated sting between handlers and are the handlers assumed to do this?
- In a event chain, is throwing an exception in an event handler a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that the event system was primarily designed (or at least: documented) as a read-only notification system. However, it is possible to do what you want by creating your own subclassed Event that defines a public property for the data you want to pass around.

For example, start with a custom event class:

```
class MyEvent extends \yii\base\Event
{
    public $data;
}
```

Trigger this event:

```
$event = new MyEvent([
    'data' => 'hello world'
]);

$this->trigger('myEvent', $event);

echo "After passing through the entire event chain, data is now: " . $event->data;
```

And add behaviors (or handlers) that listen to it:

```
public function onMyEvent($event)
{
    $event->data .= ', goodbye world';
}
```

If all went well, this should end up echo'ing `hello world, goodbye world`